# rnotebook latex issue

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, rstudio, rnotebook

Apologies in advance because I do not know how to communicate this question via code.

I have an `R Notebook`  document with some latex (maybe not formally latex, but it's mathematical notation). Previously, when the document was in visual mode, I could see my notation inside the notebook. Now, when I compile the document to a pdf the notion appears, however, the notation is no longer visible in visual mode. Does anyone know what is wrong? My first thought was it could be due to an update; however, I am fairly certain that I have not updated anything since.

Comment: What code is not shown in visual mode anymore?

Comment: Only code that produces mathematical notation.